# What is the regex for the finding the string with the pattern ALXXXXX in another string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to find the string of pattern ALXXXXX inside another string. 
For example I want to look for the string **AL00123** in the string **Data Stage AL00123**

I have tried the following in Java.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("AL\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchString);
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
```

this always returns a false. **What is wrong with my code?**

I want to achieve the following

1. Determine if the search string contains ALXXXXX.
2. Retrieve the value of ALXXXXX.
3. I want to do this in Java.

Following are the various ways ALXXXXX may occur in the any of the following ways

1. Data Stage_AL00123
2. Data Stage AL00123
3. Data Stage(AL00123)
4. Data Stage(_AL00123)
5. Data StageAL00123

Finally

1. The string will always begin with AL
2. The string will always have 5 digits following AL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Matcher#matches` matches the regex pattern against the whole input string. You want to use [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) instead.

You can also reduce the regex to `AL\\d{5}`.

Comment: the `start` method returns the starting index of the location. So call `start` and then  did a `substring` using the index.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `Matcher.matches()`, which only returns `true` if the string exactly fits the pattern. For your purpose, you'll want to use `Matcher.find()`